# Gameball xorg.conf configuration

Tags: linux-mint, libinput

So my Gameball finally arrived, and I loved it. Now it comes the fun part: configuration.

When it first arrived both scroll areas where working. But the I want both upper buttons to be left and right click, below buttons to be backward and forward, left middle to be middle click and I want both scroll areas to work.

I'm using Linux Mint, but it shouldn't change much in other linux versions.With xinput I got the following button maps:

```
Button         Code
Left upper        1
Left middle       2
Left lower        8
Right upper       3
Right middle      Internal – DPI change
Right lower       9
Left scroll area  6 and 7
Right scroll area 4 and 5
```

I configured it changing the ButtonMapping in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf to this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "- GameBall"
    MatchProduct "- GameBall"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*" 
    Driver "libinput" 
    Option "ButtonMapping" "8 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 9" 
    Option "ScrollButton" "3" 
    Option "ScrollMethod" "button"
EndSection
```

However the left scroll area isn't working. How can I configure ButtonMapping to use the 2 areas ?

The strange thing is that is I remove this section from 40-libinput.conf, the buttons aren't in the desired configuration but both areas work.

Another strange thing is that when I change ButtonMapping order the button codes reported by xinput change. I'm certainly missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Left area "wasn't working" because it's the horizontal scroll and I was trying it in a site. When I tried it in a spreadsheet larger than the screen, by some "magic" reason it started working.  LOL. Sorry.

But I'll leave the question as a reference for people to find Gameball configuration easily.